# Lucene.net metaphone implementation error

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I'm New to lucene. Can somebody provide some information as what went wrong in this implemention of lucene.net metaphone. The index is created but when i search for the word "Kool" no result is obtained though it is indexed with metaphone analyser. But if the word "cool" which is the actual word is searched then result is obtained.

```
public virtual void testKoolKat(string sIndexPath,string sDatatoCheck)
{

    Lucene.Net.Store.Directory luceneIndexDirectory = new MMapDirectory(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sIndexPath));           

    Analyzer analyze = new MetaphoneReplacementAnalyzer();   

    IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, analyze);
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(luceneIndexDirectory, conf);

    Document doc = new Document();            
    doc.Add(new TextField("contents", "cool cat", Field.Store.YES));
    writer.AddDocument(doc);
    doc = null;
    writer.Commit();

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.Open(luceneIndexDirectory);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Query query = (new QueryParser(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "contents", analyze)).Parse(sDatatoCheck);             

    var collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(500, false);

    searcher.Search(query, collector);
    var oHitColl = collector.GetTopDocs().ScoreDocs;
    for (int i = 0; i < oHitColl.Length; i++)
    {                
        Document oDoc = searcher.Doc(oHitColl[i].Doc);
        string sDocID = oDoc.Get("contents").Trim();
    }

    luceneIndexDirectory.Dispose();
    writer.Dispose();
    reader.Dispose();
    searcher = null;

}


public class MetaphoneReplacementAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
     public virtual TokenStream tokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
     {
           return new MetaphoneReplacementFilter(new LetterTokenizer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, reader));

     }
      protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
     {

    string[] sStopWordsList = new string[] { "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by", "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such", "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these", "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with" };
    Collection<string> stopWords = new Collection<string>(sStopWordsList);             
    CharArraySet stopSet = new CharArraySet(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, stopWords, false);


    Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, reader);
    TokenFilter filter = new LowerCaseFilter(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, tokenizer);
    filter = new StopFilter(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, filter, stopSet);

    return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
    }
}

public class MetaphoneReplacementFilter : TokenFilter
{
      public const string METAPHONE = "metaphone";
      private Metaphone metaphoner = new Metaphone();
      private CharTermAttribute termAttr;
      private TypeAttribute typeAttr;
      public MetaphoneReplacementFilter(TokenStream input) : base(input)
      {
            termAttr = AddAttribute<CharTermAttribute>();//                AddAttribute(typeof(CharTermAttribute));
            typeAttr = AddAttribute<TypeAttribute>();// (typeof(TypeAttribute));
      }

      public override bool IncrementToken()
      {
            //if (!input.incrementToken())
           //{
            //    return false;
            //}
             string encoded;
             encoded = metaphoner.Encode(termAttr.ToString());
             termAttr.Append(encoded);
             typeAttr.Type = METAPHONE;
             return true;
       }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you search for kat?

Comment: Same no result. but if search for cat then there is result

Comment: Have you looked into this? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Phonetic/4.8.0-beta00005

Comment: How to use thes phonetic actually? There is no sample code at all.